# SQL query where() date's year is $year

Tags: php, sql

I store dates in my database in a column of `date` data type.

Let's say I have column `date` where I store data like this "2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-02-02" etc.

Now I need to make SQL that selects only rows where `date` is equal to `2012`

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date=hasSomehowYearEqualTo=2012`

What would be the query like?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do **NOT** use `YEAR(date)` - this will calculate `YEAR(date)` for all dates, even for those, you never use. It will also make use of an index impossible - worst case on the DB layer.

Use

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$year-01-01' AND '$year-12-31'"
```

As a general rule: If you have the choice between a calculation on a constant and a calculation on a field, use the former.

Comment: Great point about calculations. You can also do `WHERE \`date\` LIKE '$year-%'`.

Comment: @ceejayoz This is just as bad! it creates the String representation for all dates, no index used ... if you have the choice between a calculation on a constant and a calculation on a field, use the former. LIKE is a calculation on the field!

Comment: This is definitely the better solution. Especially if you have indexing on date.

Comment: @EugenRieck I get the same execution plan for both when I do an `EXPLAIN`. It appears that MySQL is intelligent enough to figure it out for dates.

Comment: Is this work ? Feb month it only 28 days  but here u place d 31 any one confirm this?

Comment: @ßãlãjî Most of the time December has 31 days.

Answer (score 23):

Check out the [`YEAR()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function for MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(date)=2012
```

Answer (score -3):

select * from table where DATEPART(YEAR,[DATE])=2012