# Return date as year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I wrote this little search query:

```
 User.where("strftime('%Y', birthday) = ?", 1994)
```

But somehow i get no search resuts although i now that i have several users with their birthday in 1994. In the Users Table `birthday` is defined as `date`

Now i have two ideas how i could solve my problem:

1.I could check what the result of `"strftime('%Y', birthday)` is for a specific user or the whole user collection.  **But i dont know the expression!** Maybe you know the expression?

2.You know what i did wrong and you have an answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails you can write the query like:

```
User.where("birthday BETWEEN '?-01-01' AND '?-12-31'",1994,1994)
```

See this post for why this kind of format is good performance-wise when compared to something that uses "YEAR": [SQL query where() date's year is $year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186741/sql-query-where-dates-year-is-year).

Answer (score 0):

Your mileage may vary but I've gotten around some of these issues by querying the date column using it's underlying string format...

```
User.where("birthday like ?", "1994-%")
```

I'm too lazy to checkout sqlite's support for regexen but if you can use them then you could also try

```
User.where birthday: /^1994-\d{2}-\d{2}/
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use something like
`User.where("YEAR(birthday) = ?", 1994)`
Ref:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year

Comment: i think the error here is to wrap 1994 in quotes. You are comparing a string date with integer date. You should use it like `User.where("strftime('%Y', birthday) = '?'", 1994)`, notice the  extra quotes